# Add string parameter to style xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-styles

I have a special question about call of style in xml.

Actually when I the call of a style. In xml I do like that to apply one specific style to an object:

```
        style="@style/CustomButton"
```

What I need is to create a style with a string parameter to call it and give him my string parameter.

For example I want to create a style like that in my styles.xml :

```
<style name="CustomButton">
    <item name="android:layout_alignBottom">%s</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignTop">%s</item>
    <item name="android:layout_toLeftOf">%s</item>
    <item name="android:layout_toStartOf">%s</item>
</style>
```

I want to call my style with something like that

```
    style="@style/CustomButton", "@+id/menu_myhistory_imageview"
```

Then if it's work I'll be able to have one style for x other buttons which are exactly the same but with only these parameters which are different :

"android:layout_alignBottom"

"android:layout_alignTop"

"android:layout_toLeftOf"

"android:layout_toStartOf"

In advance thank you for your help.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge, and you can achieve what you require (although more verbose) through style inheritance - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: @veritas1 thank you for your fast answer. I'll see that.